# Dax code to do "turnstile" type counting of entries

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to get Power BI to generate the list of numbers under the "Turn" column (in yellow). these values currently are not on the worksheet.[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRxqw.png).

Comment: Can you clarity what you are looking for? What's your desired output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of information. What I am trying to do is have a turnstile type counter for items within Power BI. So lets say that ID A (from image) starts a process on January 1, 2022 and then ends that process on January 5th, 2022. I want that to be "Turn 1". Then ID A starts a process on January 8th, 2022 and ends it on January 10th, 2022. I want that to be "Turn 2". If ID B starts a process on January 3rd, 2022 and ends on January 5th, 2022, I want that to be "Turn 1". That way I can see how much time on Turn 1 takes for ID A or ID B or I can avg. the two.